# Test Class for method with List<List<Ids>>

Tags: unit-test

Hi Salesforce Experts,

I have a created a apex method which is invoked from a screen flow to mass approve records selected by the user from the data table component. This is working as intended, however, I am unclear on how to call this method from the test class. Any guidance you can provide on this would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

My Apex Class that receives a String with list of records to selected by user to approve:

```
public class MassApproveReject
{
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Mass Approve Records'
                     description = 'Approve the list of records that are selected by the user. This is intended to be invoked from a screen flow after logged user has selected the records that needs to be approved.'
                     )
     public static List<String> approveRecs(List<List<Id>> recordIds) {
     //Empty lists will not be passed to this method. It will be validated in the screen flow that calls this Apex

        List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest> requests = new List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest>();
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> piWorkItems = [
            SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId 
            FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem 
            WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId IN :recordIds.get(0)
              AND ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'
              ];
        
        List<String> approvedListIds = new List<String>();
            
       //Set approve for each record
        for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem piWorkItem : piWorkItems){
              Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
              req.setWorkitemId(piWorkItem.Id);
              req.setAction('Approve');
              req.setComments('Approved using Mass Approval Flow');
              requests.add(req);     
        }
        
        //Approve all records
        try{
            Approval.ProcessResult[] processResults = Approval.process(requests); 
            approvedListIds.add('Success');
            return approvedListIds;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            approvedListIds.add('Failure');
            return approvedListIds;
            }    
    }   
}
```

My Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class MassApproveRejectTest{
@isTest
public static void CanApprove() {
  //create record
  List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
  acc = [Select ID from account where Global_ID_Desc__c = 'International Customer' limit 1];
  Commitment_And_Rebate__c testCR = new Commitment_And_Rebate__c (Account__c = '0017i00001SR5p7AAD', Year__c='2021', Commitment_Type__c = 'RCGL', Current_Commitment_Amt__c = 1000000, PDP_Program__c = 'RCL Tier 1' );
  insert testCR;
 
 List<Id> testIds = new List<Id>();
 testIds.add(testCR.id);
//Submit for Approval
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest testApproval = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
testapproval.setComments('Submitting for approval from test class');
testApproval.setobjectid(testCR.id);
Approval.ProcessResult result1 = Approval.process(testapproval);


//Call approveRecs method in MassApproveReject Class

//MassApproveReject massAprRej = new MassApproveReject();
//MassApproveReject.approveRecs(new List<List<id>>()); 
MassApproveReject.approveRecs(new List<List<id>>(testIds));


   }
  }
```

Error Msg: Different error messages based on the ways I try to invoke the class. However, most of them are very similar to "Error: Compile Error: Invalid initializer type List found for List<List>: expected an Integer or a List of type List"

Thank you,
Sugi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MassApproveReject.approveRecs(new List<List<id>>(testIds));
```

Should be:

```
MassApproveReject.approveRecs(new List<List<id>>{testIds});
```

You use the `{}` notation to initialize a collection with an initial list of values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this @sfdcfox. The solution worked. Have a wonderful rest of the week!